# GetWindowLong() - Change in behaviour introduced with Creators Update breaks my win32 application

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

A recent Creators Update made to Windows 10 has broken my application code that uses Win32 API GetWindowLong().

Prior to Windows 10 Creator Update, one process (say process A) was able to call GetWindowWord()/GetWindowLong() APIs on another process' window handle (say process B) even if process B (Main Thread) was blocked in some system call (eg waiting on a mutex to be released). So, process A was able to query the reserved memory of a window owned by process B using these APIs successfully in spite of process B being blocked.

However, with Creator Updates applied on Windows 10, process A gets blocked when it calls these APIs on a window belonging to process B when process B (Main Thread) is blocked.

I simulated this scenario by creating 2 stand-alone Win32 apps representing process A and process B. On a Windows 10 system with Creators Update applied, process A hanged when it called GetWindowLong()/GetWindowWord() on a window belonging to process B while process B (Main Thread) was waiting on a mutex. In other words, the calls to GetWindowLong()/GetWindowWord() never returned thus making process A hang.

However, when I test the same scenario with my stand-alone apps on a Windows 10 system without the Creators Update or an earlier version such as Windows 7, the calls to GetWindowLong()/GetWindowWord() APIs in process A return successfully even as process B is waiting on a mutex to be released.

To demonstrate the above problem, here's the code for both Process A and Process B.
To see the problem, run process A and process B. Then, find out the window handle of Process B's window (eg by using Spy++) and then paste it into process A's window's edit field. Then click on OK. A message box displaying the LONG value set in process B's window's extra memory (using SetWindowLong()) is shown.
So far, so good.
Now, go to process B's window and make it hang by clicking on the "Block" button. This will make the process "B" (main GUI thread) wait on a mutex that is never going to be released and hence process B is going to hang.

NOW, go back to process A's window and again click on OK (assuming the edit field still has the same window handle of process B that you pasted earlier).

NOW, here's the difference in behaviour:

On Windows 10 WITHOUT the Creators Update and on earlier Windows versions such as Windows 7, as before (ie when the process B did not hang), a message box displaying the LONG value set in process B's window's extra memory (using SetWindowLong()) is shown.

On Windows 10 WITH the Creators Update,process A hangs because the call to SetWindowLong() made using process B's window handle never returns making process A hang.

Pls suggest me how to get around this change in behaviour on Windows 10 Creators Update so that my application does not hang.
Any ideas/help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code for Process A.

```
/* Process A */
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

int count = 0;
int count1 = 0;
TCHAR str[1000];

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowFunc(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);

HWND g_hwndEdit, g_hwndButton;

#define ID_EDIT (3456)

#define ID_OK (3457)

TCHAR szWinName[] = TEXT("MyWin");

HINSTANCE g_hInst = NULL;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInst,HINSTANCE hPrevInst,LPSTR lpszArgs,int nWinMode)
{
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wcl;
    g_hInst = hThisInst;
    wcl.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcl.hInstance = hThisInst;
    wcl.lpszClassName = szWinName;
    wcl.lpfnWndProc = WindowFunc;
    wcl.style = CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    wcl.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcl.hIconSm = NULL;
    wcl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    wcl.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcl.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcl.cbWndExtra = 44;
    wcl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcl)) return 0;
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,
        szWinName,
        "Process A",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HWND_DESKTOP,
        NULL,
        hThisInst,
        NULL
        );    
    ShowWindow(hwnd,nWinMode);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowFunc(HWND hwnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    LONG l;    
    HWND hwndOther = hwnd;
    char s[] = "Paste the window handle (in HEX) of Process B's window on which you wish to call GetWindowLong() in the edit field and click on OK.";

    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    static int cxClient = 0, cyClient = 0;

    char btnText[1001];

    switch(message){

    case WM_CREATE:

        g_hwndEdit = CreateWindow ("edit", NULL,
                         WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL |
                                   WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT,
                         200, 200, 200, 200, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_EDIT,
                         g_hInst, NULL) ;

        g_hwndButton = CreateWindow(                       
                        "Button",
                        "OK",
                        WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,
                        500,
                        200,
                        150,
                        50,
                        hwnd,
                        (HMENU)ID_OK,
                        g_hInst,
                        NULL
                        );

        return 0;

    case WM_SIZE:

        cxClient = LOWORD(lParam);
        cyClient = HIWORD(lParam);

        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:

        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        TextOut(hdc, 10, 100, s, strlen(s));

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        return 0;


    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED && LOWORD(wParam) == ID_OK)
            {
                GetWindowText(g_hwndEdit, btnText, 1000);
                sscanf(btnText, "%x", &hwndOther);
                l = GetWindowLong(hwndOther, 24);
                sprintf(str, "The LONG value at offset 24 of the window with handle 0x%x is %d.", hwndOther, l);
                MessageBox(hwnd, str, "", 0);
            }
        }

        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;        
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd,message,wParam,lParam);
}
```

And here's the code for Process B:

```
/* Process B */
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

int count = 0;
int count1 = 0;
TCHAR str[1000];

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowFunc(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);

TCHAR szWinName[] = TEXT("MyWin");

HINSTANCE g_hInst = NULL;

HANDLE g_hThread, g_hMutex;

HWND g_hwndButton;

#define ID_BUTTON (3456)

//worker thread fn
DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(LPVOID p)
{
    g_hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, "HELLO_MUTEX");
    // this worker thread now owns the above created mutex and goes into an infinite loop so that
    // the mutex is never released
    while (1){}
    return 0;
}

// main (GUI) thread
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInst,HINSTANCE hPrevInst,LPSTR lpszArgs,int nWinMode)
{    

    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD threadld;
    // create a worker thread that will create a mutex and then will go into an infinite loop making sure that the mutex is never released
    // and thus when the main (GUI) thread calls WaitForSingleObject() on this mutex handle, it is going to block forever.
    hThread = CreateThread(NULL,
                            0,
                            ThreadFunc,
                            0,
                            0,
                            &threadld);

    // make the main (GUI) thread sleep for 5 secs so that by the time it wakes up, the worker thread will have created the mutex and gone into an infinite loop
    Sleep(5000);
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wcl;
    g_hInst = hThisInst;
    wcl.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcl.hInstance = hThisInst;
    wcl.lpszClassName = szWinName;
    wcl.lpfnWndProc = WindowFunc;
    wcl.style = CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    wcl.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcl.hIconSm = NULL;
    wcl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    wcl.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcl.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcl.cbWndExtra = 44;
    wcl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcl)) return 0;
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,
        szWinName,
        "Process B",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HWND_DESKTOP,
        NULL,
        hThisInst,
        NULL
        );
    SetWindowLong(hwnd, 24, 135678);
    ShowWindow(hwnd,nWinMode);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowFunc(HWND hwnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    char strr[1000];    
    char s[] = "Click on the \"Block\" button below to make the main (GUI) thread block by waiting on a mutex forever since the mutex will never be released.";
    HWND hwndOther = hwnd;

    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    static int cxClient = 0, cyClient = 0;

    switch(message){

    case WM_CREATE:


        sprintf(strr, "Window created - handle is %x.\n", hwnd);
        OutputDebugString(strr);

        g_hwndButton = CreateWindow(                       
                        "Button",
                        "Block",
                        WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,
                        10,
                        120,
                        50,
                        50,
                        hwnd,
                        (HMENU)ID_BUTTON,
                        g_hInst,
                        NULL
                        );

        return 0;

    case WM_SIZE:

        cxClient = LOWORD(lParam);
        cyClient = HIWORD(lParam);

        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:

        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        TextOut(hdc, 10, 100, s, strlen(s));

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        return 0;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED && LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTON)
            {                
                MessageBox(hwnd, "Main (GUI) Thread going in blocking state by waiting for mutex forever now", "", 0);
                WaitForSingleObject(g_hMutex, INFINITE);              
            }
        }

        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;        
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd,message,wParam,lParam);
}
```

Comment: If this really is something that changed in the CU there's unlikely to be anything you can do about it.

Comment: really gui thread must not wait and "hung". he must permanent run message loop. so solution very simply - not wait , without message processing, in gui thread

Comment: Thanks RbMm for pointing me in the right direction. Your suggestion implied using MsgWaitForMultipleObjects() which won't make the GUI thread in Process B hang and hence the GetWindowLong() made in Process A on Process B's window handle will return normally without hanging.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution which is to use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects() inside Process B so that it keeps looking for messages in the queue as well in addition to waiting on the mutex.
By doing this, the GetWindowLong() call made in Process A on Process B's window handle will return normally without blocking and hence the problem is solved.

Here's the updated code of Process B, the change is in "Block" button click handling WM_COMMAND case (Process A code remains the same):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

int count = 0;
int count1 = 0;
TCHAR str[1000];

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowFunc(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);

TCHAR szWinName[] = TEXT("MyWin");

HINSTANCE g_hInst = NULL;

HANDLE g_hThread, g_hMutex;

HWND g_hwndButton;

#define ID_BUTTON (3456)

//worker thread fn
DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(LPVOID p)
{
    g_hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, "HELLO_MUTEX");
    // this worker thread now owns the above created mutex and goes into an infinite loop so that
    // the mutex is never released
    while (1){}
    return 0;
}

// main (GUI) thread
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInst,HINSTANCE hPrevInst,LPSTR lpszArgs,int nWinMode)
{    

    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD threadld;
    // create a worker thread that will create a mutex and then will go into an infinite loop making sure that the mutex is never released
    // and thus when the main (GUI) thread calls WaitForSingleObject() on this mutex handle, it is going to block forever.
    hThread = CreateThread(NULL,
                            0,
                            ThreadFunc,
                            0,
                            0,
                            &threadld);

    // make the main (GUI) thread sleep for 5 secs so that by the time it wakes up, the worker thread will have created the mutex and gone into an infinite loop
    Sleep(5000);
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wcl;
    g_hInst = hThisInst;
    wcl.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcl.hInstance = hThisInst;
    wcl.lpszClassName = szWinName;
    wcl.lpfnWndProc = WindowFunc;
    wcl.style = CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    wcl.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcl.hIconSm = NULL;
    wcl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    wcl.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcl.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcl.cbWndExtra = 44;
    wcl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcl)) return 0;
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,
        szWinName,
        "Process B",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HWND_DESKTOP,
        NULL,
        hThisInst,
        NULL
        );
    SetWindowLong(hwnd, 24, 135678);
    ShowWindow(hwnd,nWinMode);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

BOOL waitWithMessageLoop(HANDLE hMutex, BOOL &bExit)
{
    BOOL bContinue = TRUE;
    bExit = FALSE;
    while(bContinue)
    {
        DWORD dwReturn = ::MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &hMutex, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);
        if(dwReturn == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            // our mutex got released
            bContinue = FALSE;
        }
        else if(dwReturn == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1)
        {
            MSG msg;
            while(::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                {
                    bExit = TRUE;
                    bContinue = FALSE;
                    break;
                }
                ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
                ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // MsgWaitForMultipleObjects() returned error
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowFunc(HWND hwnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    char strr[1000];    
    char s[] = "Click on the \"Block\" button below to make the main (GUI) thread block by waiting on a mutex forever since the mutex will never be released.";
    HWND hwndOther = hwnd;

    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    static int cxClient = 0, cyClient = 0;

    switch(message){

    case WM_CREATE:


        sprintf(strr, "Window created - handle is %x.\n", hwnd);
        OutputDebugString(strr);

        g_hwndButton = CreateWindow(                       
                        "Button",
                        "Block",
                        WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,
                        10,
                        120,
                        50,
                        50,
                        hwnd,
                        (HMENU)ID_BUTTON,
                        g_hInst,
                        NULL
                        );

        return 0;

    case WM_SIZE:

        cxClient = LOWORD(lParam);
        cyClient = HIWORD(lParam);

        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:

        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        TextOut(hdc, 10, 100, s, strlen(s));

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        return 0;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED && LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTON)
            {                
                MessageBox(hwnd, "Main (GUI) Thread going in blocking state by waiting for mutex forever now", "", 0);
                // disable the "Block" button
                EnableWindow(g_hwndButton, FALSE);
                //WaitForSingleObject(g_hMutex, INFINITE);// do NOT use this as this cause the GetWindowLong() call made in Process A to hang
                BOOL bExit = FALSE;
                waitWithMessageLoop(g_hMutex, bExit);
                if (bExit)
                {
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                }
            }
        }

        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;        
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd,message,wParam,lParam);
}
```

Thanks,
--ANURAG.